# Separating duality for TVS?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

What is the modern concept (term) for "separating duality" (dualité séparante in french) in the sense of Bourbaki (TVS Ch II § 6) as explained in the following ?

```
Let E, F be two k-vector spaces and B : E x F --> k a bilinear form, one 
says that B puts F,G in duality. The duality is separating in E iff for 
all x\not=0 in E it exists y\in F such that B(x,y)\not=0. It is separating 
in F iff for all y\not=0 in F il exists x\in E such that B(x,y)\not=0. 

The duality is called separating iff it is separating in E and F.
```

I am currently using this notion in the context of Hopf algebras (where it is not usual).

Anyone knows the modern terms ? links ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 1987 [translation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61715-7_2) by Eggleston & Madan renders it exactly as you do: "We say that the duality defined by $B$ is *separating in* $F$ (resp. *in* $G$) if ..."

Comment: @François Ziegler Thank you. I have this translation but would like to know if these terms are still up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I made this a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @François Ziegler : Point taken.

Comment: Another notion often used (in particular, in the study of duals of locally convex spaces) is the following: a family $\alpha_x$ of linear, (continuous) functionals on $E$ "separates points of $E$" if for all non-zero $e \in E$ there exists $x$ such that $\alpha_x(e) \neq 0$. So I think "duality separating points" should work also.

Comment: @TobiasDiez Thanks. Without better update, I will take your advise and write "The spaces E,F are in duality separating points"

Comment: ... or better "The spaces E,F are in duality separating "their" points"